# gst_parse_launch() throwing 'asssertion failed'

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying the basic tutorial that's been given in the gstreamer's site. However, this code:

```
GstElement *pipeline;
GstBus *bus;
GstMessage *msg;
GError* err = (GError*)malloc(sizeof(GError));

/* Initialize GStreamer */
gst_init(NULL, NULL);

/* Build the pipeline */
pipeline =
        gst_parse_launch(
                "playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm",
                &err);

gLogi("test") << err->message;

/* Start playing */
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

/* Wait until error or EOS */
bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

/* Free resources */
if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref(msg);
gst_object_unref(bus);
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref(pipeline);
```

Is giving me the following errors:

```
[INFO] test: 

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_parse_launch_full: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_element_set_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_element_get_bus: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered: assertion 'GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_element_set_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(VideoDeneme.exe:14524): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:03:04.979: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
```

The gLogi is a special function that basically serves as a output function.

I am building my project with cmake, and gstreamer-1.0 library is linked properly. What could be the reason I am getting this error? I also tried to link every possible dependency for the gstreamer and it's dependencies, however since i have static library, I don't think this is needed. So what could be causing this?

Comment: Seems like I don't have the playbin plugin, since my error message gave: `no element "playbin"`

Answer (score 1):

```
GError* err = (GError*)malloc(sizeof(GError));
```

should be

```
GError* err = NULL;
```

Comment: This is not a fix to my problem, but made my error show up.

Comment: Well if there is error during pipeline creation all code after that is pointless as they require the pipeline.

Comment: Is there a way I can download playbin plugin seperetaly? Because the problem seems to be that

Comment: It should come with a proper installation of GStreamer. We now nothing about your platform or installation procedure.

Comment: I am currently using a windows 10 x86_64, also installed the gstreamer from MSYS2 and copied all the content inside mingw64 folder, to my project's mingw64 folder.

Comment: `gst_init()` will try to scan for plugins. MSYS2 can be difficult as the default path to look for may be in Unix path format. Read up upon `GstRegistry` on how to point it to the correct plugin location. It would be easier if you go with the regular GStreamer binary releases on Windows imo.